# SQL:Calculate number of repetitions of a field from one table to another field in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this :

```
| ID | REAGENT |
|----|---------|
|  1 |       0 |
|  2 |       0 |
|  3 |       1 |
|  4 |       2 |
|  5 |       2 |
|  6 |       1 |
|  7 |       3 |
|  8 |       1 |
|  9 |       4 |
| 10 |       3 |
| 11 |       6 |
| 12 |       4 |
| 13 |       1 |
| 14 |       0 |
| 15 |       0 |
| 16 |       2 |
| 17 |      11 |
| 18 |      23 |
| 19 |      11 |
| 20 |       7 |
| 21 |       6 |
| 22 |      10 |
| 23 |       1 |
| 24 |      11 |
| 25 |      15 |
| 26 |       4 |
```

and i use this query to calculate number of repetitions of each 'ID' field  in 'reagent' field in the same table

```
  SELECT 
   b.ID,(SELECT count(a.reagent)FROM mytb AS a WHERE a.reagent=b.ID ) AS reagentCount 
FROM mytb AS b

| ID | REAGENTCOUNT |
|----|--------------|
|  1 |            5 |
|  2 |            3 |
|  3 |            2 |
|  4 |            3 |
|  5 |            0 |
|  6 |            2 |
|  7 |            1 |
|  8 |            0 |
|  9 |            0 |
| 10 |            1 |
| 11 |            3 |
| 12 |            0 |
| 13 |            0 |
| 14 |            0 |
| 15 |            1 |
| 16 |            0 |
| 17 |            0 |
| 18 |            0 |
| 19 |            0 |
| 20 |            0 |
| 21 |            0 |
| 22 |            0 |
| 23 |            1 |
| 24 |            0 |
| 25 |            0 |
| 26 |            0 |
```

this query have a correct response  but is a too slow !

I wanted to know if there is a faster way to calculate?
I'm grateful for your guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query does not look too bad. I think your problem is lack of proper indexes.

If you simply add index on `reagent` column, it should work much faster:

```
CREATE INDEX mytb_reagent_ix ON mytb(reagent);
```

Easiest way to confirm that your query is performing fast is to take a look at execution plan using [EXPLAIN statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) and make sure that primary or secondary keys are used for all query steps - I did it for you in this [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ce54/6).

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS repetitions, REAGENT FROM mytb GROUP BY REAGENT
```

You could even sort by number of repetitions to see the ones with the most repetitions first:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS repetitions, REAGENT

FROM
mytb

GROUP BY
REAGENT

ORDER BY
repetitions DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. this query just calculate reputations of  each reagent field and not calculate ID reputation in reagent field